# Difference Between xmlrpc and apache thrift

Tags: xml-rpc, thrift

I need to know the difference between the xmlrpc and apache thrift. Which one is speed and ease to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Difference**

XML-RPC is XML based, this it is by nature more verbose, leading to larger messages and mopre traffic. In addition, XML must be parsed, while Thrift's binary format is quite effective, with regard to both size and processing speed.

**Which one is speed**

One of Apache Thrift's main goals is efficiency (read: speed)

**Which one is ease to use**

With Apache Thrift, you get a single package which contains compiler and runtime libraries for approx. 20 languages, covering Windows, Linux and Apple platforms. In contrast, XML-RPC (as well as SOAP) relies on what you get with your IDE and/or what is available as 3rd-party components, including any incompatibilities that may or may not be cause by that <sup>1)</sup>.

---

<sup>1)</sup> <sub>Incompatibilities may not exist in theory, but they for sure do in real life. Situation may be better with XML-RPC, as it is much simpler than SOAP.</sub>

<sup>2)</sup> <sub>Disclaimer: My opinion may be biased.</sub>